# Do positive-definite elements in finite-dimensional $*$-algebras over $\mathbb R$ always admit square roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $*$-algebra over $\mathbb R$. We say that an element $x \in A$ is *positive definite* if $x$ admits an inverse and if $x = y y^*$ for some $y \in A$. Does every such $x$ admit a $z \in A$ such that $x = z^2$? If someone has references for me to read, I would appreciate that.

I think the Wedderburn-Malcev theorem can help here, as well as Hermite interpolation. But non-commutativity seems like an obstacle.

Comment: Note that $x$ being invertible is necessary, otherwise $A=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ with $*$ being transpose would be a counterexample with $x=\begin{bmatrix}1& i\\i&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume that a $*$-algebra just means an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with a linear operation satisfying $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$ and $x^{**}=x$ (as at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-algebra).  If so, you can just take $A=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with $(x_0,x_1)^*=(x_1,x_0)$.  Then take $x=(-1,-1)$ and $y=(1,-1)$ so $x=yy^*$ and $x$ is invertible but $x$ has no square root.  If you want any more axioms then you should specify them.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I think I misstated the question. But thank you for this answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

(I initially overlooked that one is looking for a finite-dimensional $A$. Otherwise, the following is a counterexample.)

You could take $A$ to be the field of rational expressions in the variable $X$ with complex coefficients and turn it into a $*$-algebra by writing $X^* =X$ and $z^* = \overline{z}$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If you now take $y = X+i$, we get that $x = y y^* = X^2 + 1$. There are no polynomials $P$ and $Q$ in the variable $X$ such that $\frac{P(X)^2}{Q(X)^2} = X^2+1$, which follows for instance by looking at zeros and poles.

Comment: That example isn't finite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, though.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I overlooked that crucial condition. So my answer is not very useful here.